# OctoberCMS does not show static pages from template

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have a fresh installed OctoberCMS with the static pages plugin.
I have a template from another OctoberCMS installation with the static pages and their content.
For example I have a main page with the URL `/`.
This is also displayed correctly when I call it in the browser, but it does not appear in the backend under the static pages. So I can't edit it there anymore.
Also I can not create a new page with the URL `/`. The system seems to have understood that the page exists. But why is it not displayed in the backend?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing the `static-pages.yaml` file.

You'll find this in `/themes/yourOldTheme/meta/static-pages.yaml`

So you'll need to copy all the .htm files out of your old theme like you've already done. But you also need this static-pages.yaml so they all appear in the static pages list on the OctoberCMS backend.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, it may be possible that page can come from the `CMS/Editor Module`.

You can check the full article here [How To Add Pages In October Cms](https://tutorialmeta.com/octobercms/how-add-pages-october-cms).

Please check `CMS module`, maybe your page can come from there if it's not
defined in static pages.

---

> In OctoberCMS v1

[image: october-cms-cms-module]

> In OctoberCMS v2

[image]

If you doublet please comment.

Comment: Ah I see in "CMS -> Content" the static-pages folder with my htm files. But I cant edit them in that place

Comment: Alright, but is there a way to "import" my static pages? I just want to copy them from one instance to another

Comment: yes those `your_theme/content/static-pages/*.htm` these all are your `static pages`. you can copy and paste them to another instance. just make sure that folder structure  `your_theme/content/static-pages/` looks like this.

Comment: But thats exactly what I did to get that problem now ;)